# При выборе в форме атрибута enctype="multipart/form-data" русские символы отображаются некорректно

Tags: php, html

Обновил вчера версию *php* на локальном хосте, и теперь в формах при выборе атрибута `enctype="multipart/form-data"` русские символы отображаются некорректно:

> (ÐÑÐ¾Ð´Ð°Ð¶Ð° 1-ÐºÐ¾Ð¼Ð½. Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¾ÑÑÑÐ¾Ð¹ÐºÐ¸ Ð² ÐÐ°Ð¼ÐµÐ½Ð½Ð¾Ð¹
>   Ð³Ð¾ÑÐºÐµ, ÑÐ". ÐÐµÐ¼Ð°Ð½ÑÐºÐ°Ñ, 9

`Mb_detect_encoding` говорит о том, что это *utf-8*. Да и сам я выводил значения массива `$_POST` в самом начале *php*-файла, и уже тогда русские буквы выводились неверно, т.е. бд здесь не при чем.

Когда же меняю атрибут формы на `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, все ок. Но мне нужен именно `multipart/form-data` для отправки файлов.

Буду рад любой помощи или альтернативе.

Comment: А сайт у вас в какой кодировке работает?

Comment: Все в utf-8: заголовки - header utf-8, meta utf-8 и в htaccess utf8

Comment: Апач меняли вместе с php?

Comment: нет, только php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения вашей проблемы добавьте атрибут в форму

```
<form ... accept-charset='utf-8' ...
```

Или пропишите в .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Если кодировка сайта не utf-8, то замените значение

**UPD:**

Проблема решена отключением **mbstring.encoding_translation**: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.encoding-translation

Comment: и то, и другое уже прописано - не робить) буквально на днях все работало, обновлял версию php и не работает, хотя может взаимосвязи и нет

Comment: Версия php какая? Как вариант прописать: 
header("Accept-Charset: utf-8");

Comment: Была 5.3, теперь 5.4, еще xdebug подключал. Добавление заголовка header("Accept-Charset: utf-8") ничего не изменило. Повторюсь, когда меняю на application/x-www-form-urlencoded все работает нормально.

Comment: http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.encoding-translation

Comment: спасибо, отключил, заработало)  может подскажете в чем прикол?

Comment: По описанию функции я думаю все ясно )

Comment: ладно, подрасту - пойму, еще раз спасибо